# Flex: Resize image to content in cross axis

Tags: css, image, flexbox

I have a flex container with two flex items inside: An H1 and an IMG.

The flex direction is row.

I want the size of both items in the cross-axis (vertical) to be dictated by the H1's height.

This works as expected when the height of the H1 is bigger than the original resolution of the image, the image scales to match the H1's height.

```css
*
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body
{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
h1
{
  font-size: 250px;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <h1>Hi</h1>
    <img src="https://revmd.com/wp-content/uploads/medical-coding-icon.jpg" alt="">
</body>
```

However, when the H1's height is smaller than the original resolution of the image, the image won't resize to the H1's height, rather its height will be determined by its default resolution.

How can I achieve the desired effect, preferably preserving the image's aspect ratio?

Answer (score 1):

set image with height and width equal the number font size of text. and have `object-fit:contain` to keep aspect ratio of image

```css
*
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body
{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
h1
{
  font-size: 20px;
}
img {
width: 20px;
height: 20px;
object-fit:contain;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <h1>Hi</h1>
    <img src="https://revmd.com/wp-content/uploads/medical-coding-icon.jpg" alt="">
</body>
```